# remote disable apache server and mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I have a potential client who would like to use my web app but will only do so if they can have it on a server in their own office instead of using it on my hosted server. I am tempted to just say no, but at the same time I could use the extra client and wanted to investigate options of being able to disable the service in the event of non-payment.

I was thinking along the lines of having a cron script check a specific location on my server each day and based on the response either keep operating or disable the apache/mysql services. I could do this except one aspect eludes me. In the old days I used to be able to write a small c app using setuid(0) to execute commands as root. This seems to be no longer the case due to security which is fair enough, but I will need something like this to be able to shutdown apache and mysql.

Is there another option?

I have just also thought as I was typing that my cron script (if told to disable) could write a .htaccess file redirecting everything to a disabled message.

Has anyone done this before and if so how did you do it?

The server will be running Ubuntu.

Comment: I've never done anything like this before, but I'd imagine a heartbeat back to your server seems logical until your server goes down for whatever reason and you've got a lot explaining to do.

Comment: Unless you can encrypt your source code or obfuscate it beyond readability, any measures you take will be short lived as your client could just edit your application to do away with the validation. Your only real options here are legal. Write a binding contract and charge appropriately taking into account your loss of IP

Comment: @melee : It would need to be written to cater for such a situation, such as only disable if the heartbeat is dead for a few days. (My server is in a data center and is managed so the most downtime I have had has been about 20 mins)

Comment: @Phil : I agree that with physical access there isn't much that can be done if they decide they want it. I will be looking into such a contract anyway if I go down this path.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to solve communication problems technically, because you will fail.

Instead, only hand over the work if payment has been done. Create a contract that handles the details, incl. usage rights (how many copies etc.).

Job done. Extra client for you. No hassle. No complex script that might even break your site.

Comment: :) seems like that is the general recommendation. I like the technical approach over communication but I guess that's just the programmer in me.

Comment: If you are worried about the client not paying, then you don't need that client. Hakre's advice is solid. If the client appears to be a problem already, you will spend far more time on them then it's worth, time much better spent finding a quality client.

Answer (score 2):

I once heard of a gentleman who had a "nuke script" which he kept embedded in case of non-payment. When final debts were settled, he would enter a password and it would erase itself and it would act as if it were never there. If debts were not settled, it would back-up the clients data to his machine, and then wipe *everything*. Most clients never knew, those who did paid.

Here's a better solution (and one which does not involve a cron job or a back-door with a secret key): tell them that the finished product can be on their server, but you will host it until it is ready to go live. Then, when it is time, transfer all necessary data to the production server. Only promise support if they continue paying. If they don't continue paying, then that is no sweat off of your back.

Comment: that does raise another issue.. having to support a remote server :( lol. Thanks

Comment: @Tim. Not at all. Once the site is live, the site is the client's problem and you will not touch it unless they pay. Ideally, you can write the terms in a way which is very beneficial to you. And, if the client is paying well, what does it matter if it is remote?